# Termination of Apache HTTP kills Java superprocess as well

Tags: java, apache, termination

I have following problem in Ubuntu: I start an Apache HTTP server within my Java application executing "httpd -f _CONFING_FILE_ -D FOREGROUND". The Apache HTTP runs as a subprocess of my Java application. Subsequently, if I stop the Apache using "httpd -k stop -f ..." or "kill _APACHE_PID_", the Java application exists as well. How is that possible and how can I prevent the termination of the Java application?